# After displaying the data on the page, they are cut off after the point asp.net

Tags: css, asp.net, model-view-controller, letters

I have a problem. When I loaded data in page, they cut off after the point. And I don't know why! In database I have table and fields have type nvarchar(50-*). Data I keep in: text.text e.g. `Minsk.Labanka 17` and page display only Labanka 17. Maybe problem with type?
Typical using model and contoller.

Below is the code line where getting problem:

```
<p class="rating-number">@Html.Label(Model.servicesModel.vRaiti‌​ng)</p>
```

Comment: please share some code for the reference to this issue.

Comment: share your code where you getting problem...;)

Comment: `<p class="rating-number">@Html.Label(Model.servicesModel.vRaiting)</p>` here I have problem with raiting. I keep value `7.1` but displayed only `1`.

Comment: @Zicise You should edit your question, instead of putting it as a comment. The question should speak for itself.